# Unable to assign value to Array get set

Tags: asp.net, arrays, c#-4.0, properties

I am very new to .net. I have a class which has get and set property. Now if I want to assign value to this array , I am facing null reference.  I am unable to assign value `ORM.a[i] = dr["SUMMARY"].ToString();`

```
public class method1
{
    public string[] a{ get; set; }
    public double[] b{ get; set; }
}

 publiv method1 GetResponseData()
{
    int i = 0;
    method1 ORM = new method1 ();

    foreach (DataRow dr in dtResultHistory.Rows)
    {
        ORM.a[i] = dr["SUMMARY"].ToString()  ;
        ORM.b[i] =   Convert.ToDouble( dr["AVG_TIME"]);

    }

    return ORM ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are facing null exception because you havent created instace of it.

something like

```
string[] a = new string [size];
```

If you are not having details about how many element i going to be there , i suggest you make use of List.

Example :

```
public class method1
{
  public method1()
  {
     a = new List<string>();
     b = new List<double>();
  }

            public List<string> a{ get; set; }

            public List<double> b{ get; set; }
}
```

you code after this will be

```
 public method1 GetResponseData()
 {
     int i = 0;
     method1 ORM = new method1();

     foreach (DataRow dr in dtResultHistory.Rows)
     {
        ORM.a.Add(dr["SUMMARY"].ToString());
        ORM.b.Add(Convert.ToDouble( dr["AVG_TIME"]));
    }
    return ORM ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error happens because both `a` and `b` property hasn't been initialized. Initialized them first in the class constructor:

```
public class method1
{
    public method1() {
        this.a = new string[100]; // We take 100 as an example of how many element the property can handle.
        this.b = new double[100];
    }

    public string[] a{ get; set; }

    public double[] b{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: adding  method1 {
        this.a = new string[100];
        this.b = new double[100];
    } gives me an error  "invalid token ' {' in class struct or interface member declaration"

Comment: @maddy whoops I forgot to put the `()` sign, I have edited my answer.. Now it is `public method1() { this.a = new string[100]; this.b = new double[100]; }`

Comment: @Maddy - you cannot allocate 100 element on array without knowing size..its waste of memory space

Comment: @Maddy As Pranay Rana says, if you do know the size, then it is okay to use array.. Otherwise consider using a list.